# Trouble getting query result to display

Tags: php, mysql

My query is working below, except I can't display the results which should be "2" (the results of the distinct count). Instead I get "Total Authors: ID"

```
//var_dump Result:

array(1) {
[0]=> object(stdClass)#349 (1) {
["COUNT(DISTINCT writing.ID)"]=> string(1) “2″
}
}

//Code:

$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT writing.ID)
FROM writing
LEFT JOIN stories on writing.SID = stories.SID
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON writing.ID = wp_users.ID        
WHERE (stories.SID = $the_SID)"
);

echo var_dump($authors);
print "Total Authors:" .$authors[0]->writing.ID ."<p>";
```

Comment: "I know there are two different user ID numbers stored in my writing table under ID".  Please provide sample data and what you want to return.  The query looks okay.

Comment: Query was working fine it turned out. Just can't get result to display (see modified post)

Comment: What do you get for the `var_dump`?

Comment: You can see the var_dump in the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the output of `var_dump`, your required value is being stored as a member `COUNT(DISTINCT writing.ID)` of the object. There are a few workarounds you can follow.

1. Store the index as a separate variable and then use it when printing.

   ```
   $t = "COUNT(DISTINCT writing.ID)";
   print "Total Authors:" .$authors[0]->$t . "<p>";
   ```
2. Use an alias in the MySQL query.

   ```sql
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT writing.ID) AS writingID
   FROM writing
   LEFT JOIN stories ON writing.SID = stories.SID
   LEFT JOIN wp_users ON writing.ID = wp_users.ID        
   WHERE (stories.SID = $the_SID)
   ```

   and then,

   ```
   print "Total Authors:" .$authors[0]->writingID . "<p>";
   ```